# Notes synchronisation with google account, uncountable notes generated

Tags: macos, gmail, notes.app

I have setup my macbook to sync with my google account for notes and apparently for each note that i start to write on my mac several versions, i believe all versions of the notes (after each modification) are saved within all mail in my gmail, however only the final version of the note is kept under the label notes. Is there any way to prevent mac notes to save drafts on the google server?